# Would like to use this SQL Server date exactly in Oracle query

Tags: sql-server, oracle

`2017-11-17 06:35:41.0000000` - this is a value of a column `FileProcessDate` in a SQL Server table. I am trying to build an incremental logic and I would like to use this date (directly) in Oracle to build that logic.

I am using the following query in Oracle

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENT 
WHERE TIMESTAMP > TO_DATE('2017-11-17 06:35:41.0000000', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS')
```

But I am getting an error

> not a valid month

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use correct timeformat:

```
SELECT * 
FROM EVENT 
WHERE TIMESTAMP>TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-11-17 06:35:41.0000000','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=46db2e91a38f0f5d9944a68d860092db)**